# Iterating through CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to loop through a CSV and run a web request. I can't get it past the first row in the CSV.

The CSV is being exported from Mac Excel as a list of 10 items in 10 rows / 1 column.

```
def AddTokens(request):
    import csv

    tokenList = []
    output = 0

    apikey = "12345"
    restkey = "12345"
    URL = "https://api.web.com/1/install/"
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-web-Application-Id': apikey, 'X-web-REST-API-Key': restkey}

    with open('/Users/name/Desktop/test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
        deviceTokens = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for token in deviceTokens:
            deviceToken = token[0].replace("/", "")
            deviceType = "ios"
            pushToken = "pushtoken_" + deviceToken
            payload = {"deviceType": deviceType, "deviceToken": deviceToken, "channels": ["", pushToken]}

            r = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

    t = get_template('addpush.html')

    html = t.render(Context({'output': output, 'tokenList': tokenList, 'deviceTokens': deviceTokens, 'token': token}))

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't get it past the first row'? What happens, and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Looks like you only read one line.

Comment: The loop stops at the first result. I can never get it to the second row. I assumed as it looped through "deviceTokens" - it would go through and 10 "token."

Comment: Your indentation is a bit all over the place there..However, I guess you're making 10 post requests, but your `deviceTokens` context is going to be an iterable that's already exhausted...

Comment: Why would it be already already exhausted?

Comment: @Rangers4me because you've read through the file (now at the end), then after that pass it to the context... so you've got an iterable that'll yield nothing... Are you sure it's the first item it's stopping on, or is it that you're just getting the last item?

Comment: It's definitely the first item.

Comment: In other words, when `t.render()` is called after the `for` loop is finished, `deviceTokens` will be an exhausted`csv.reader` iterator.

Comment: Is there a way to render the view so I can see the status of the loop, while still looping through it?